# Facing error java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy9.proxyClassLookup() on run appium with POM

Tags: testng, appium, mobile-automation, pom

Hi everyone im facing this error on run appium with POM
here is complete error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy9.proxyClassLookup()
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.prepareAnnotationMethods(AppiumByBuilder.java:85)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.getFilledValue(AppiumByBuilder.java:92)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.createBy(AppiumByBuilder.java:148)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.getBys(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:133)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.buildMobileNativeBy(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:177)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.buildBy(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:216)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:65)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:52)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.decorate(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:56)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.decorate(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
    at pages.loginPage.<init>(loginPage.java:36)
    at MainFiles.baseOfProject.login(baseOfProject.java:66)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy9.proxyClassLookup()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2195)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.prepareAnnotationMethods(AppiumByBuilder.java:83)
    ... 42 more
```

Here is my test base class

```
package MainFiles;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.reuseableComponents.objects;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import pages.loginPage;

public class baseOfProject extends objects {
    InputStream inputStream;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() throws Exception {
        try {
            props = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";
            inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
            props.load(inputStream);
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus");
            capabilities.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11");
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.dstgyr.dastgyr");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","MainActivity");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,
                    "C:/Users/Uzair Shahid/eclipse-workspace/RetailerApp_Version1/src/main/resources/app/final stg.apk");
            capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS, true);
            capabilities.setCapability("automationName", props.getProperty("automationName"));
            capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
            capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
            capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
            capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
            URL url = new URL(props.getProperty("appiumURL"));
            driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(url, capabilities);

            System.out.println("Base started Sucessfully...........");

            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }


    @Test
    public void login() throws Exception {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        loginPage = new loginPage(driver);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        loginPage.changePhoneLanguage();

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

here is my object class

```
package com.reuseableComponents;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import pages.loginPage;

public class objects {

    protected static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
    protected static Properties props;
    protected DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    protected static WebDriverWait wait;
    protected loginPage loginPage;


    
}
```

here is my loginPage class

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.reuseableComponents.objects;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;

public class loginPage extends objects {

//  public loginPage(AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver) throws Exception {
//      this.driver = driver;

    public loginPage() {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[5]/android.widget.TextView[1]")
    MobileElement changeLanguage;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[1]")
    MobileElement selectEnglishRadio;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[3]/android.widget.TextView")
    MobileElement ConfirmLangugeButton;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.EditText")
    MobileElement phoneNumner;

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]")
    MobileElement nextButton;

    public void changePhoneLanguage() throws InterruptedException {
        changeLanguage.click();
        selectEnglishRadio.click();
        ConfirmLangugeButton.click();
        System.out.println("in the login page");
    }
}
```

And here is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>appiumBase</groupId>
    <artifactId>new</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>new</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
                <testng.version>6.14.3</testng.version>
        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This is a guess, but the different versions of testng specified in your pom.xml (the `properties` child node vs the version in the `dependencies` seems pretty suspicious

Comment: Got it @ernie what's your suggestion? What version should I make in pom.xml

Comment: You should make it match whatever version you wrote your code to use.  I don't know if you're using testng 6 or 7?  Specifying one version as a property and then another version when the dependency is defined seems like a smell for sure.